# How to preserve data type for raster tif object

Tags: r, tiff, raster

I have a tif raster created in ArcMap.  The pixel type of this raster is signed integer.

When I create a raster object based on the tif and check its datatype, it get converted to an unsigned integer:

```
> r_tif <- raster("test.tif")
> dataType(r_tif)
[1] "INT1U"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: For byte type files that are read via rgdal the dataType() function does not always give the correct type as rgdal only reports 'Byte' (not signed or unsigned). But the file is not changed and should be read correctly.

Comment: Interestingly, if I create a raster object with a grid (I converted the tif to a grid in ArcGIS), I do see the object keeps the "INT1S" data type.  
Also, I did notice that when I look at the values of the tif raster ( using values(r_tif) ), the negative values get replaced with 255 minus the negative value ( -1 becomes 255,etc. )